# How to await the generation of containers in an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, dispatcher, itemcontainergenerator

I have a `SettingsWindow`, in it there is an audio file selector which has a context menu. Some code accesses the `MyAudioFileSelector` computed property before it can get the `AudioFileSelector` because the `AudioFileSelector` is just inside a `DataTemplate` of an item in an `ItemsControl` that has not yet generated its containers at that moment. I tried to defer the access to `MyAudioFileSelector` using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` with `DispatcherPrority.Loaded`, but the item containers are still not yet generated at that moment.

The code that accesses the `MyAudioFileSelector` is the method that applies one of the many settings inside the user-selected data file. This method is called from the `Window`'s `Loaded` event handler synchronously for each setting in the program's data files' schema.

I am very new to async-await programming, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12858501/258462) but I am not sure how this helps me, and I read [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) but I am still not sure what to do. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32656431/258462) a but the only answer, unaccepted, seems similar to what I already use below:

```cs
MySettingsWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    [...]
}), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
```

## A part of the XAML

*(`InverseBooleanConv` just makes `true`, `false`, and `false`, `true`)*

```xml
<ItemsControl Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0,-0.6,0" Grid.Row="0"
ItemsSource="{Binding SettingsVMs}" x:Name="MyItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <xceed:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConv"/>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:AudioFileSettingDataVM}">
            <local:AudioFileSelector MaxHeight="25" Margin="10" FilePath="{Binding EditedValue, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <local:AudioFileSelector.RecentAudioFilesContextMenu>
                    <local:RecentAudioFilesContextMenu
                        PathValidationRequested="RecentAudioFilesContextMenu_PathValidationRequested"
                        StoragePropertyName="RecentAudioFilePaths"
                        EmptyLabel="No recent audio files."/>
                </local:AudioFileSelector.RecentAudioFilesContextMenu>
            </local:AudioFileSelector>
        </DataTemplate>
        [...]
```

## Parts of the code-behind

### In MainWindow.xaml.cs, the beginning of the `Window_Loaded` handler

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VM.ClockVMCollection.Model.FiltersVM.Init();
    VM.Settings.IsUnsavedLocked = true;
    VM.ClockVMCollection.Model.IsUnsavedLocked = true;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, SettingDataM> k in VM.Settings)
    {
        ApplySetting(k.Value);
    }
    [...]
```

### In MainWindow.xaml.cs, in the method `ApplySetting`

```cs
case "AlwaysMute":
    VM.MultiAudioPlayer.Mute = (bool)VM.Settings.GetValue("AlwaysMute");
    break;
case "RecentAudioFilePaths":
    MySettingsWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MySettingsWindow.MyRecentAudioFilesContextMenu. // here, MyRecentAudioFilesContextMenu is null, this is the problem
            LoadRecentPathsFromString(VM.Settings.GetValue("RecentAudioFilePaths") as string);
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    break;
case "RecentImageFilePaths":
    MySettingsWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MySettingsWindow.MyRecentImageFilesContextMenu. // here, MyRecentImageFilesContextMenu is null, this is the problem
            LoadRecentPathsFromString(
                VM.Settings.GetValue("RecentImageFilePaths") as string);
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
    break;
    [...]
```

### In the `SettingsWindow` class

```cs
internal AudioFileSelector MyAudioFileSelector
{
    get
    {
        foreach (SettingDataVM vm in MyItemsControl.ItemsSource)
        {
            if (vm is AudioFileSettingDataVM)
            {
                return (AudioFileSelector)MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(vm);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
internal ImageFileSelector MyImageFileSelector
{
    get
    {
        foreach (SettingDataVM vm in MyItemsControl.ItemsSource)
        {
            if (vm is ImageFileSettingDataVM)
            {
                return (ImageFileSelector)MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(vm);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
internal RecentAudioFilesContextMenu MyRecentAudioFilesContextMenu
{
    get
    {
        return MyAudioFileSelector?.RecentAudioFilesContextMenu;
    }
}
internal RecentFilesContextMenu MyRecentImageFilesContextMenu
{
    get
    {
        return MyImageFileSelector?.RecentImageFilesContextMenu;
    }
}
```

The bug is in the two C# comments in one of the code snippets above, null reference exceptions.

I think I could attach in the `MainWindow` a handler to `SettingsWindow`'s `ItemsControl`'s `ItemContainerGenerator`'s `StatusChanged` event and then continue the initialization of the window, including the loading of all the settings, but I wonder if there is a more orderly/correct way.

Thank you.

Comment: Is `MyRecentImageFilesContextMenu` a property of the window, i.e. does the window itself have a `ContextMenu`?

Comment: @mm8 No, it is a property of the `ImageFileSelector`, which is a `Control` inside the `SettingsWindow`. I just needed a way to access it directly.

Comment: Well, there is no more "orderly/correct" way than waiting until the element has been created and the `ContextMenu`property has actually been set.

Comment: Pretty much any time you write code references ui directly like that, you'd do better using mvvm. Work with data rather than ui.then you won't have any itemgenerator code to have any null reference problems.

Comment: @Andy How can I use MVVM if I want to load something from a data file, or save something into a data file? Thank you.

Comment: @Andy I posted a new related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57974279/258462). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your `ItemsControl` in the code-behind under the variable name `MyItemsControl`, then you can add an event handler for the `ContainerGenerator` `StatusChanged` event:

```cs
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    //Subscribe to generated containers event of the ItemsControl
    MyItemsControl.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles changed in container generator status.
///</summary>
private void ContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var generator = sender as ItemContainerGenerator;
    //Check that containers have been generated
    if (generator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated ) {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

I really recommand not to use this if what you're after is simply save/load data from a file, as they are completely unrelated.